# Check if a given string exists as a key in nested hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Given a hash -

```
hash = { 
         1 => {"ID"         => ["NUMBER", 11]   }, 
         2 => {"TITLE"      => ["VARCHAR2", 5]  },
         3 => {"FIRST_NAME" => ["VARCHAR2", 50] }, 
         4 => {"LAST_NAME"  => ["VARCHAR2", 50] },         
         5 => {"BIRTH_DATE" => ["DATE", -2]     }
       }
```

and 2 input parameters - `"FIRST_NAME"` and `["VARCHAR2",50]`.

What is the most elegant way to do -

1. check whether `"FIRST_NAME"` exists as key of any nested hash.
2. And if it exists whether value of `hash[3]["FIRST_NAME"]` is equal to second parameter i.e. `["VARCHAR2",50]`.
3. And if these 2 parameters match then return the key whose value is this nested hash i.e. 3 in this case

Currently I do the following -

```
array = hash.values.map {|h| h.to_a}.flatten(2)
puts hash.key(Hash["FIRST_NAME",["VARCHAR2",50]]) if !(index = array.index("FIRST_NAME")).nil? ? array[index+1] == ["VARCHAR2",50] : false # 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find a lot of information in you check the [`hash api`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-key-3F).

```
a = 'FIRST_NAME'
b = ['VARCHAR2', 50]

hash.each do |k, v|
  if v.key?(a)            # ①
    return k if v[a] == b # ② and ③
  end
end
```

You could also write it as below actually because if it does not contain the key, it will never match and just go to the next occurence.

```
hash.each do |k, v|
  return k if v[a] == b
end
```

Your example only show hash with one pair, if there is more your need to do a new `each` on `v`.

Comment: just for fun I wanted to do it without `each` but having done a benchmark `each` wins by 5:1 and besides "simple is elegant", so I'll accept your suggestion. Though you should update your code to return key `k` rather than variable `a` as that's the required output.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like what your doing defeats the purpose/performance of a hash.

You should be using the (I assume) unique names "ID", "TITLE", "FIRST_NAME"... as your top level keys; the numbers 1-5 seem unused.

Searching a hash map by key is fast, having to map all values into an array than do a linear search on the array is slow.

Comment: these named keys are not unique. You could have `6 => {"FIRST_NAME" => ["VARCHAR2", 100] }` in addition to `3 => {"FIRST_NAME" => ["VARCHAR2", 50] }`

Comment: @Ashish Saihgal - if that's the case then the best you can do is loop through the hash values checking the key iteratively. It'll be less expensive than remapping the hash into an array, then searching.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method `key` for doing just that:

```
hash.key({"FIRST_NAME" => ["VARCHAR2",50]}) # => 3
```

Comment: oh yeah, stupid me! I have used it above after having done what key already does for me. +1 to you.